# Php define() page access denied

Tags: php

My problem is with `define()` and `header()`.

`header()` part does not work in video player.

Example: 
[image]

**index.php**

```
define('access', true);
```

**video.php**

```
if(accsess == true){ 
    echo "Hacking?";
} else { 

    $token = $_GET['token'];

    $query4 = "SELECT url FROM video WHERE token = $token";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query4);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $direction = $row['url'];

    if($row){
        header("Location:".$direction);
    }else {
        echo "Hacking?";
    }

}
```

Comment: "access" != "accsess"

Comment: I apologize, I should have written if (access == true) {. And the error continues

Comment: So what does your browsers development console say about that http requests response?